# MapBox Autofill Full Address

Tags: mapbox

I am trying to use MapBox Autofill feature to get a full address in an address input field, but I don't see an autocomplete tag that includes full addresses.

I tried to use multiple autocomplete tags to get street addresses, cities, states, etc. without showing them (by using type="hidden"), but then values from the hidden fields don't get submitted along with with the main input field (address):

```
<form action="/results" method="post">
    <input name="address"  placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" autocomplete="street-address" />
    <input name="city" placeholder="City"  autocomplete="address-level2"  type="text" disabled="true" />
<p>
  <center><button type="submit" class="button btn-send disabled">Search</button></center>
</p>
</form>
```

Can someone help me understand how I can submit full address through the form without showing secondary input fields?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the [retrieve](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/api/web/autofill/?size=n_10_n#mapboxaddressautofill.event:retrieve) event from mapbox-search, which returns an `AutofillRetrieveResponse` (promise) from which you can extract the full address.

In the following example I'm getting the full address and setting it as the value of the input field, but you could change this according to your needs.

```js
const autofill = mapboxsearch.autofill({
  accessToken: YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN,
});

autofill.addEventListener('retrieve', async (event) => {
  const fullAddress = event.detail.features[0].properties.full_address;
  this.inputTarget.value = await fullAddress;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I am not JS savvy, so would you mind helping me modify the original script to make the full address retrieval work? 

`<script id="search-js" defer src="https://api.mapbox.com/search-js/v1.0.0-beta.13/web.js"</script>
<script>const script = document.getElementById('search-js');
        script.onload = function() {
            mapboxsearch.autofill({
                accessToken: '***'
            });
        };
    </script>`